# Cross-browser replacement of HTML checkbox with highlighted image

Tags: jquery, html, css, checkbox

I have a list of HTML checkboxes that I'd like to change into images that can be selected or deselected by the user.

In essence I'm trying to achieve something like [this](https://vid.me/yVCd) using pure CSS, if possible.

I have got it working in Chrome using:

```css
.check_test {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: blue;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
.check_test:checked {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input class="check_test" type="checkbox" name="check1" style="background-image: url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/39/Croquetplayers.jpg/220px-Croquetplayers.jpg); " />
</form>
```

However, according to [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-appearance) this isn't going to work on IE.

Is there another CSS option that will achieve the same effect? If not, is there a simple jQuery solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use `label` you need assign an id to the checkbox.

http://jsfiddle.net/k47qcb7d/2/

```
.check_test:checked + label {
    position: relative;
}

.check_test:checked + label:before {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    background: black;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

IE9+, but if you use jQuery to do the selector, it can work on all even IE6 I think.